# Possible to calculate iterated count of timestamps relative to one another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This question is a bit complicated but to make it as simple as possible:

I have a list of timestamps (it is in the millions but let's say for simplicity sake it is much smaller):

```
order_times
-----------
2014-10-11 15:00:00
2014-10-11 15:02:00
2014-10-11 15:03:31
2014-10-11 15:07:00
2014-10-11 16:00:00
2014-10-11 16:04:00
```

I am trying to build a query (in PostgeSQL) that would allow me to determine the number of times a an order_time occurs within 10 minutes of 2 order_times prior to it (and no more).

In the sample data above:

- first time stamp is considered 0 as there were no orders before it
- second timestamp is considered 0 as it was within 10 minutes of it
  prior but there was only 1 request before it
- third timestamp is considered 1 because there were at least 2 orders within 10 minutes of it
- (and so on)...

I hope this is clear!

Comment: Note: I just used a cross-join and referenced the results then filtered on order_times <> order_times and set an order_time window with grouping. If there are better ways to handle I am definitely interested in learning though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look at the first previous, just the one 2 prior to each.  If that is within 10 minutes, then the one after it will be also.

Best way is to get the data that is important to you into a single row, so you can do set operations on it.  For that, use the windowing function ROW_NUMBER() and a self join.  This is the MS SQL way of doing what you want.

```
WITH T1 AS (
SELECT ID, Order_Time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Order_Time) AS RowNumber FROM myTest)

    SELECT T1.ID,T1.Order_Time, T2.ID AS CompareID,T2.Order_Time AS CompareTime
    FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 AS T2 ON T1.RowNumber-2 = T2.RowNumber 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(n,t2.Order_Time,t1.Order_Time)<=10
```

First we create a query that has the row numbers, then use it as an inline table to do a self join to build a row that contains each order, and the one that happened 2 orders prior to it.  Then just do a simple date comparison to select out the rows you want.